# Is 'performing safe' an idiomatic expression?

Tags: usage

***stay safe*** is grammatically correct and ***play it safe*** is an idiomatic expression. But how about ***performing safe***? Can I use ***performing safely*** instead of ***performing safe*** in the context?

> Given the risks of taking risks, there are obvious upsides to not
> taking risks. You ***stay safe***. You never get uncomfortable. And
> you minimize the risk of failure.

> It’s a simple choice because would you rather take risks and give
> yourself a strong chance of real success or ***play it safe*** and
> guarantee failure?

> You need to prepare yourself for performing at the next level. And
> ***performing safe*** just won’t cut it.

[Risk it for the Biscuit](https://Given%20the%20risks%20of%20taking%20risks,%20there%20are%20obvious%20upsides%20to%20not%20taking%20risks.%20You%20***stay%20safe***.%20You%20never%20get%20uncomfortable.%20And%20you%20minimize%20the%20risk%20of%20failure.%20%20%20%20It%E2%80%99s%20a%20simple%20choice%20because%20would%20you%20rather%20take%20risks%20and%20give%20yourself%20a%20strong%20chance%20of%20real%20success%20or%20***play%20it%20safe***%20and%20guarantee%20failure?%20%20%20%20You%20need%20to%20prepare%20yourself%20for%20performing%20at%20the%20next%20level.%20And%20***performing%20safe***%20just%20won%E2%80%99t%20cut%20it.)

Comment: To ***play [it] safe*** (don't be "adventurous", avoid risky alternatives) is an established idiomatic usage, but *to perform safe* is at the very least an "unusual" sequence (and *to perform **safely*** has no special idiomatic currency or significance).

Answer (score 1):

"You need to prepare yourself for performing at the next level. And performing safe just won’t cut it." sounds more than a little odd to me (AME speaker).

"You need to prepare yourself for performing at the next level. Playing it safe just won’t cut it." on the other hand would be entirely normal.